# FFmpeg concatenate video with audio repeat audio until video finishes

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

i am using

```
ffmpeg -i concatWithnoSound.mp4 -i music.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4
```

to concatenate video with audio file i have a problime my video file is dynamic so it maybe 15 sec or 2 min what i need is repeat the audio file to as far as the video is playing is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy. The best supported way (no need for new `ffmpeg` versions) is to create a concat file:

```
file 'music.mp4'
file 'music.mp4'
file 'music.mp4'
...
```

long enough to make sure your sound is repeated often enough for your desired video length.

Then use

```
ffmpeg -i concatWithnoSound.mp4 -f concat -i concatfile -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: Audio re-encode can be skipped if source is already MP4.